jQuery selector keeps returning an empty string
I don't know if it's the [data-a-target="smc-detail-page-thank-you-summary-amount-collected-date"] jQuery selector that the browser doesn't like, but I keep getting an empty string and fail to extract the date on this very trimmed and dumbed down piece of code that I copy-pasted in a "test.html" file:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Extract Date</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  let dateString = $('[data-a-target="smc-detail-page-thank-you-summary-amount-collected-date"] .expandable-text-wrapper').text();
  console.log(dateString);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="tw-flex">
  <div class="row-layout__column-2 tw-mg-r-3">
    <div class="tw-mg-b-2 tw-overflow-hidden">
      <div class="tw-lg-mg-b-05">
        <p class="tw-amazon-ember tw-amazon-ember-regular tw-c-text-base tw-font-size-6 tw-regular" title="Collected on">Collected on</p>
      </div>
      <div data-a-target="BasicInfoChildren">
        <p class="claim-summary-expandable-text__body--collapsed tw-c-text-white tw-font-size-6 tw-md-font-size-5" data-a-target="smc-detail-page-thank-you-summary-amount-collected-date">
          <div tabindex="-1" class="expandable-text-wrapper">Jun 18, 2024</div>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-layout__column-2">
    <div class="tw-mg-b-2 tw-overflow-hidden">
      <div class="tw-lg-mg-b-05">
        <p class="tw-amazon-ember tw-amazon-ember-regular tw-c-text-base tw-font-size-6 tw-regular" title="Sent to">Sent to</p>
      </div>
      <div data-a-target="BasicInfoChildren">
        <p class="claim-summary-expandable-text__body--collapsed tw-c-text-white tw-font-size-6 tw-md-font-size-5" data-a-target="claim-summary-publisher-name">
          <div tabindex="-1" class="expandable-text-wrapper">Amazon Games library</div>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>

I even verified with Codeium and ChatGPT, asking them if my code was right and they both said it was fine.
I tried using this selector though: let dateString = $('.expandable-text-wrapper').text(); and it outputs "Jun 18, 2024Amazon Games library", so this is driving me crazy.

Well when your code runs, is it possible that the DOM does not look exactly like the DOM you show in the post? Are portions loaded dynamically?

I BELIEVE the problem here is that a <div> cannot be a child of a <p>, so the parser is closing the <p> before opening the <div>.  If you change that inner <div> to a <span>, your code works.

@Pointy Nope, this is the final html. That's why I said I put it all in a test.html file, so it's a contained example, you can test it on your end and will see the same result

@TimRoberts I had never heard about this, good job for the find, however this is on the Amazon website (where I'm trying to extract all the timestamps of my orders) so I don't have control over that <div> inside the <p>. I could try to replace it with jquery but I might have the same issue selecting the inner <div>

jQuery does allow you to pick the "next sibling" that matches instead of the "first descendent".  That might do it for you.

Oh.. I already copy-pasted the page's entire DOM in regex101 and replaced the inner <div> with a <span>. But if you want to formulate an answer, I'll accept whatever is your best suggestion since you are the one who figured out the issue!
